are FaaS Serverless Variables Reliable?
I'm writing an API that is provided through the FaaS Serverless service of Netlify.
To transfer Data Between Requests, I stored data on a temporary variable outside function declaration as it's useble by many functions instances, but I noticed some errors while doing so.
I tried to test it and would like to confirm my ideas.
I create an temporary variable let value = 1;
Created an Express Server that is wrapped by serverless-http that is provived as handler to Netlify.
I created one route /modify for adding 1 to value and setted a timeout to wait one second before the function timeout - to simulate the time that would take to get the data to retrieve to the user.
I created another route /getVal to print value on Netlify Console.
→ After executing modify and waiting a little, but not long enough for the function to finish, the value before the modification is rendered
→ However, at a seemingly random frequency, the rendered value is not the previous one, but the initial 1. If I change the initial value to 0, the value printed is 0 instead.
**- The seemingly random return of the initial value from the shared variable means that these shared variables aren't reliable? **
- Does the values shared among functions instances - modified by afunctions - change just after the modifier function ended?

This is one of the features of serverless architectures. There is no permanent server on which state can be stored. Depending on a number of factors, when you invoke your endpoint a second or third time, you might find that the endpoint executes on the same server, or an entirely new one with fresh state.
You should not attempt to store mutable global state in the globals of your function code. The state may or may not persist between function invocations. This makes it unreliable. If you need to store state, then connect the function to a database or other external storage service.

But it should be consistent at least during an instant on time, no?
I did some tests, subscribing all requests to an specific route to receive as response the values passed through an event call that is emitted every time the API receives an POST sending new data and just then ends the function.
However, looks like that even the event is emitted by the POST, the functions subscribed to the event emission are never called.
Same the state being mutable along time because of serverless nature, it should be consistent on one intant.
PS: all endpoints are handled at same function.

Don't rely on request being run on the same or a different function instance. How the cloud provider decides to dispatch requests to your code is not under your control. Sometimes the request will be handled by a new instance because the server is under load. Sometimes it will be handled by the same instance to reuse resources and reduce function latency. And sometimes it will be handled by a different instance, because the previous instance was killed for being idle for too long. This behaviour is not under your control. Do not rely on it one way or the other.
